# Throw error on max instantiations of class

Tags: c++, class, error-handling, instance, throw

I want my program to throw an error when a defined maximum number of objects of a certain class (MAX) is reached. I must limit the number of instantiations because I'm working with a framework that provides a limited amount of resources.

Currently I have the following (simplified):

```
class Resource {
    private:
    static int count;

    public:
    Resource();
};

int Resource::count = 0;

Resource::Resource() {
    if (++count > MAX) {
        throw std::domain_error("Cannot create more resources.");
    }
}
```

Is the use of `std::domain_error` recommended or should I use another type? Or should I not throw an error at all and follow a different approach?

Comment: A domain error is a math thing IMHO.  Personally I would use `std::runtime_error`.

Comment: the framework should throw if it cannot provide you more ressources. What framework is it? Whats the actual size of the class? Your example has no members, hence I would not bother to limit number of instances. Or is this supposed to be a base class?

Comment: @bloody I was not questioning the usefullness of the minimal example. I was asking for the real case, because `sizeof` should make a difference. I'd expect that you can create more instances when `sizeof` is smaller

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 The framework is freeglut and I'm creating classes for lights for easier use. This is indeed supposed to be a base class for lights. Because freeglut has a limited amount of lights you can create, I thought it would be a good idea to limit the instantiations of this class in my code.

Comment: What happens when you do create more lights if you do not use your ressource counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the general question, without considering any of the details of the application.

> Is the use of std::domain_error recommended or should I use another
> type? Or should I not throw an error at all and follow a different
> approach?

Regarding which exception to throw: `std::domain_error` specifically has to do with the argument of a function being outside the allowed range, so that is not a good fit. As @NathanOliver suggests, `std::runtime_error` would be a good option. Or a custom exception derived from that.

Regarding throwing an exception or using a different approach: An important question is *when* the error is expected to happen and *who can handle it*.

Exceptions are typically used for errors that can happen during normal operation, and preferably be handled at run-time.

If the amount of resources allocated is determined during development, and excessive allocation of resources indicates a bug, then an assertion is an option:

```
Resource::Resource() {
    assert(++count <= MAX);
}
```

That will make a debug-build of the program crash (fail-fast) if the limit is exceeded, which is often quite useful during development, testing, and debugging but should obviously not be used if the limit can be exceeded in the finished product. (As assertions are typically removed in release builds it would go unnoticed and cause whatever problems or undefined behaviour exceeding the limit would cause).